# My android app banner is not showing

Tags: android, google-chrome, smartbanner

I'm adding android app banner (https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4540065577435136) on my website. I have added the manifest and the icons but it is still not appearing. Note that I am enabling the chrome flag for bypassing user engagement.

The requirements of the app banner is that the site should be in HTTPS. My site is in HTTPS but I'm using a SHA-1 certificate for this. Is there any chance that this is the problem or is there a problem with my manifest?

```
{
   "name": "Website",
   "icons": [
   {
      "src": "icon144x144",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
    ],
    "prefer_related_applications": true,
    "related_applications": [
    {
        "platform": "play",
        "id": "android.id"
    }
    ],
    "start_url": "index.html",
    "display": "standalone"
}
```

Comment: I have tested, and using the example given [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/app-install-banner/related-applications/manifest.json) is working, but as soon as I change the package for the one for my app, it stops working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have investigated this issue. If you have the app you are trying to install already installed, the banner will not show. Uninstall the app and try again. Also remember to enable this chrome flag

chrome://flags/#bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks

Maybe we should ask Google to implement a similar banner that the one that is shown on Safari, it detects if you have the app installed and shows a 'Open' button instead of 'Install' button.

Answer (score 0):

Also worth noting that if it was working before and suddenly it stops, it can be reset by clearing the browser cache in Chrome for Android.

Top Right -> History -> Clear Browsing History -> Clear Browsing Data -> Clear Data